# Hibernate envers - loading history for nested object

Tags: java, audit, hibernate-envers

I have an entity that has some list and looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOME")
@Audited
public class House {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date updateDate;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "home", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Room> rooms;

    [...]

}
```

Also assume that Room entity looks like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOM")
@Audited
public class Room {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date updateDate;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="HOUSE", nullable=false)
    private House house;

    [...]

}
```

As you see rooms are saved with cascade. Lets go to core of my question...

PRECONDITINS:

Current data in house object:

```
House:
    description: "red house"
    rooms: [room1, room2]
```

Current data in audited tables:

```
--- HOUSE_A ---
| REV | REVTYPE | ID | UPDATE_DATE     | DESCRIPTION |
+-----+---------+----+-----------------+-------------+
| 111 | 0       | 10 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | red house   |

--- ROOM_A ---
| REV | REVTYPE | ID  | UPDATE_DATE     | NAME  | HOUSE |
| 111 | 0       | 100 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | room1 | 10    |
| 111 | 0       | 110 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | room2 | 10    |
```

USER STEPS:

Update house object with these data (change house description):

```
House:
    description: "blue house"
    rooms: [room1, room2]
```

After this operation audited tables will look like this:

```
--- HOUSE_A ---
| REV | REVTYPE | ID | UPDATE_DATE     | DESCRIPTION  |
+-----+---------+----+-----------------+--------------+
| 111 | 0       | 10 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | red house    |
| 112 | 1       | 10 | 2015-08-3 12:30 | blue house   |

--- ROOM_A ---
| REV | REVTYPE | ID  | UPDATE_DATE     | NAME  | HOUSE |
| 111 | 0       | 100 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | room1 | 10    |
| 111 | 0       | 110 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | room2 | 10    |
```

Update house object with these data (do not change house object and add one room):

```
House:
    description: "blue house"
    rooms: [room1, room2, room3]
```

After this operation audited tables will look like this:

```
--- HOUSE_A ---
| REV | REVTYPE | ID | UPDATE_DATE     | DESCRIPTION  |
+-----+---------+----+-----------------+--------------+
| 111 | 0       | 10 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | red house    |
| 112 | 1       | 10 | 2015-08-3 12:30 | blue house   |

--- ROOM_A ---
| REV | REVTYPE | ID  | UPDATE_DATE     | NAME  | HOUSE |
| 111 | 0       | 100 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | room1 | 10    |
| 111 | 0       | 110 | 2015-08-3 12:00 | room2 | 10    |
| 113 | 0       | 120 | 2015-08-3 12:40 | room3 | 10    |
```

LOAD AUDITED HOUSE DATA:

```
--- current result ---
HOUSE_A(last_rev) -> HOUSE_A(112) -> 'blue house' with room1 and room2

--- expected result ---
HOUSE_A(last_rev) -> HOUSE_A(113) -> 'blue house' with room1, room2 and room3
```

Here is the problem...

Highest revision for house is 112 but last operation that I've done has been saved with revision 113 (rev entry hasn't been added to HOUSE_A because house object didn't change). I know that envers loads all data for house object that has less or equal revision. In this case last operation won't be loaded. The question is - the only way to load these kind operations (main object wasn't updated) is to update main object's (house) last update date before save so new entry will be added to HOUSE_A with the same revision as in ROOM_A?

After this 'workaround' audited tables will look like this...

```
--- HOUSE_A ---
| REV | REVTYPE | ID | UPDATE_DATE      | DESCRIPTION  |
+-----+---------+----+------------------+--------------+
| 111 | 0       | 10 | 2015-08-30 12:00 | red house    |
| 112 | 1       | 10 | 2015-08-30 12:30 | blue house   |
| 113 | 1       | 10 | 2015-08-30 12:40 | blue house   |

--- ROOM_A ---
| REV | REVTYPE | ID  | UPDATE_DATE      | NAME  | HOUSE |
+-----+---------+-----+------------------+-------+-------+
| 111 | 0       | 100 | 2015-08-30 12:00 | room1 | 10    |
| 111 | 0       | 110 | 2015-08-30 12:00 | room2 | 10    |
| 113 | 0       | 120 | 2015-08-30 12:40 | room3 | 10    |
```

Comment: Do you find a way to achieve this? i would like to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the Envers version you're using, but there is a configuration property that is enabled by default in Envers 5.x that should trigger this exact functionality:

```
org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change=true
```

Since `Room` owns the relationship to `Home`, this configuration being enabled should cause Envers to record a revision change for `Home` when the `Room` collection is modified.